# Geometric stacks, groupoids and étendues

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, stacks, algebraic-stacks

If $(C, \tau)$ is a site with pullbacks and $\tau$ subcanonical, it is well known that these things are essentially equivalent:

- Groupoids $s,t: U_1 \to U_0$ where $s,t$ are covering for the $\tau$-topology
- Geometric stacks, that is stacks (in groupoids) over $C$ with a representable $\tau$-covering from an object of $C$.
- Etendues, that is a topos over $\mathrm{Sh}_{\tau}(C)$ which is locally isomorphic to the small topos $\mathrm{Sh}(U_\tau)$ of coverings of $U \in C$.

Essentially to $U: U_1 \to U_0 \times U_0$ we associate the stackification of the groupoid functor associated to $U$. If $X$ is a geometric stack, and $U_0 \to X$ a presentation, we associate the groupoid $U_1=U_0 \times_X U_0 \to U_0 \times U_0$. If $X$ is an étendue, and $F \to 1$ is a well supported object such that $X/F=\mathrm{Sh}(U_\tau)$ with $U \in C$, then via $F \times F \to F$, we get (I think) that $X/(F \times F)$ also represents $\mathrm{Sh}(U'_\tau)$. And $U' \to U$ is the corresponding groupoid.

*Main question*: is this completely spelled out in the litterature? The closest I have been able to find is
Dorette A. Pronk, *[Etendues and stacks as bicategory of fractions](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=CM_1996__102_3_243_0)*, but she only treat some particular cases like topological stacks, differentiable stacks and algebraic stacks. What I am looking for is some kind of axiomatic treatment of geometric stacks that outlines the three approaches (and what are the exact conditions for them to be equivalent).

*Second question*: Pronk assumes in her statement on $DM$-stacks as étendues that
$X/(F \times F)$ comes from a $U'$. Does this not follow from the hypotheses (see also this [Stack project blog post](https://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Edejong/wordpress/?p=346)) ?

The situation is a bit subtle if we consider theses objects as part of a $2$-category. For example for groupoids we really want to invert weak isomorphisms. (For that I like the theory of anafunctors as in
David Roberts, *[Internal categories, anafunctors and localisations](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/26/29/26-29abs.html)*.) For étendues it is important to consider the topos over the big topos; algebraically this is the same as looking at the topos with its structure sheaf (ie see it as a locally ringed topos in the case of algebraic stacks).

The papers by David Roberts and David Carchedi seem interesting, but I have not been able to find the full link between étendues and geometric stacks completely explained. The link between stacks and groupoids is a lot more standard. For instance the post [Link between internal groupoids and stacks on a topos ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93948/link-between-internal-groupoids-and-stacks-on-a-topos) by Carchedi explains well the link between (standard) stacks over a base site and internal groupoids (or categories) in the topos.

I have a (*third and final*) related question about geometric stacks: is the correct definition the one I gave, or should we require the stronger condition that the diagonal of $X$ has to be representable as well? For algebraic stacks this is equivalent, since a surjective representable cover implies that the diagonal is representable by effectivity of fppf descent for separated locally quasi-finite morphisms. What happens for geometric stacks when this descent condition is not satisfied? Does the iterated construction even converge?

**Edit**: for the third question, in [HAG2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404373.pdf), Töen and Vezzosi show that the link between geometric stacks and groupoids is still valid in derived algebraic geometry. This is their Proposition 1.3.4.2. In their Assumption 1.3.2.2, they do assume that a $\tau$-covering satisfy the descent condition.

**I should introduce some motivations for this question**: I'd like to see a treatment of algebraic (DM) stacks from the internal point of view of their étale topoi. Standard references for schemes are Hakim's thesis, and more recently
[Ingo Blechschmidt thesis](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Using-the-internal-language-of-toposes-in-algebraic-Blechschmidt/75f2a5ce638e762ec85391b31f4d20572207e6f5), *Using the internal language of toposes in algebraic geometry.*

It seems the étendue point of view would be the best suited from an internal logic perspective. Of course the ultimate goal would probably be an internal description of (derived) algebraic geometry expressed in the logic of their $\infty$-topos via HoTT, but meanwhile I would also be happy for just an internal description of standard algebraic stacks.

Comment: I don't think geometric stacks and étendues are equivalent. For example if $(C,\tau)$ is affine schemes with the étale topology, then étendues are arbitrary DM stacks, whereas geometric stacks are algebraic stacks with affine diagonal; neither is a special case of the other.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely the type of things that make me wish for an exhaustive treatment of when the equivalence holds. Your comment show two things: 1) we want to have some kind of saturation condition on $C$, eg a geometric stack that is a sheaf should be in $C$. 2) In my assumptions I use the same type of morphisms for the topology and for presentations. So for the étale topology, we require a geometric stack to have an étale presentation, so to be DM. A more exhaustive treatment would distinguish between the topology and the presentations (like in HAG2).

Comment: So in this case the link with an étendue is less clear. Still for general algebraic stack, we can see them as  stacks for the fppf topology with an fppf presentation, or as stacks for the smooth topology (hence the étale topology) with smooth presentation. So I guess the equivalence with étendues still holds (but the only proof I know is from Pronk and she only treat the DM case).

Comment: Also the saturation condition reminds me of a comment I forgot to make on requiring $\tau$-covering to satisfy the descent condition: it looks like the key condition to bound the number of time we iterate the construction before it saturates; something like iterating n+2 time to get n-geometric stacks. We can even troncate along the way, so iterate twice to get geometric sheafs, then geometric 1-stack,  2-stacks and so on (so for algebraic stack this would go affine -> alg space with affine diagonal -> alg space -> alg stack rather than the more standard affine->schemes->alg space...).

Comment: @Marc I believe the OP is using the term "geometric stack" in a generic sense, to cover Artin, DM, differentiable, topological, etc as the site/presentation varies, rather than a technical definition. Fwiw, Damien, I prefer to call these "presentable" stacks, because of this terminology clash.

Comment: @Marc: wait, if $(C,τ)$ is affine schemes with the étale topology, then geometric stacks are stacks with an affine étale (representable) presentation, and they do correspond to étale affine groupoids and étendues (since $F$ corresponds to $U \to X$ which is étale, and representable since pullbacks are above $F$ so should be affine by definition of an étendue).

Comment: @Roberts: sorry, I'll edit!

Comment: No worries! You'd be surprised at the number of people who accidentally call me Robert, as if it's my first name... :-D

Comment: "should we require the stronger condition that the diagonal of  has to be representable as well" yes, I think so.

Comment: @David: Indeed, imposing the diagonal to be representable indeed feels more "geometric". But in this case the equivalence with the groupoid approach fails no? (Or rather we then need to impose the diagonal condition everywhere.) For the terminology, I used the one from the nlab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+stack. But I have also seen the presentable stack terminology (maybe from your articles?).

Comment: There's also the following idea: you don't just impose on your groupoids that their source and target come from a pullback-stable class, but also the diagonal map $(s,t)$. For instance, we can ask that $s$ and $t$ are étale, and that $(s,t)$ is proper. This is reflected in the condition placed on the diagonal of the stack.